# Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID # type #0x12 is not valid

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

Tell me please, why it doesn't like my layout (RelativeLayout with `@+id/row`)?

When I use it with self created adapter (layoutinflater) it works good.
And one more. I plan to use in my database bitmaps, stored like `byte[]`. Can `SimpleCursorAdapter` itself convert byte[] dates in to image (ImageView) or does it work only with texts?

**Error description**

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c006c type #0x12 is not valid
```

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mListView = ( (ListView) findViewById (R.id.notes_listView) );
    mNoteDb = new NoteDb (getApplicationContext ());
    Cursor c = mNoteDb.getTitleColumn ();

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (getApplicationContext (),
            R.id.row, // **<<< THIS ONE**
            c, new String[]{NoteDb.MainTable.COLUMN_TITLE}, new int[]{R.id.title_text_row}, 0);
    mListView.setAdapter (mAdapter);
```

**row layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/row"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_row"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
    android:text="@string/main_row_tv_date"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/note_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/main_row_icon_description"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:maxHeight="45dp"
    android:maxWidth="45dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/priority_icon"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/priority_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date_row"
    android:contentDescription="@string/main_row_icon_priority_description"
    android:maxHeight="25dp"
    android:maxWidth="25dp"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_priority_first"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text_row"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/note_icon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/note_icon"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/note_icon"
    android:text="@string/main_row_tv_title"/>
```

**Cursor query**

```
public Cursor getTitleColumn () {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = mNoteDbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase ();
    Cursor c = db.query (MainTable.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[] {MainTable._ID, MainTable.COLUMN_TITLE},
            null, null, null, null, null);
    return c;
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

you should provide a layout not an id. Replace  `R.id.row` with `R.layout.your_layout_name`

Answer (score 2):

I really bet you trying to `textView.setText(Integer)` somewhere.

### Han, didn't read question fully. Update

No, you can't place pictures in default adapter. It works only with text. You need to create your own `Adapter`. And I recommend you to switch to `RecyclerView` especially with displaying pictures,